# Texture Format In Threejs

Tags: three.js, textures

I couldn't actually understand the concept of Texture.Format in threejs Docs,
Does the luminescence format has any relationship with YCbCr format?
When I tried debugging this I got a numerical value like 1025 for format,
What does this number actually means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`THREE.LuminanceFormat` and `THREE.LuminanceAlphaFormat` representing the `internalformat` of the texture. According to the documentation of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/texImage2D) the `internalformat` specifies the color components in the texture (amount of color channels and bytes per pixel).

> When I tried debugging this I got a numerical value like 1025 for format, What does that actually means?

The value of the constant `THREE.LuminanceFormat` is `1024` and the value of `THREE.LuminanceAlphaFormat` is `1025`. These values have no further meaning since it could be anything. `three.js` internally converts them to the actual WebGL constant like so:

```
if ( p === LuminanceFormat ) return gl.LUMINANCE; // assuming p is a concrete value of a texture
```

Comment: Is this luminanceFormat same as the YUV color format

Comment: No.`YUV` is something totally different. `LUMINANCE` just represents the luminosity of a color.

Comment: So If I have a YUV video, then what format should I give for the texture?

Comment: Sry, I don't know that. What is a YUV video?

Comment: Yeah, but what do you mean with "YUV video"? What video format are you using?

Comment: Um, I think it's better to ask a new question. You should note in this question what actual video format you are using (e.g. MP4 or WebM).